# CSS box-shadow doesn't works over flash object

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex

hi I have navigation in html(bootstrap) and all other window is covered with flash(swf) object where my drop-down menu opens over flash object, I mean there is swf in background of my drop-down menu and my menu has "box-shadow" but it doesn't reflect in Firefox it only works with chrome I used following css queries without luck(See snapshots for more)

Live link is here http://csstest.coolpage.biz/

Download Link is here http://csstest.coolpage.biz/fiddle.zip

```
box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

Mozilla Snapshot
[image: Mozilla]

Chrome Snapshot
[image: Chrome]

Comment: did you try to use `hex` color instead of `rgba` , i guess it's `rgba` issue not `box-shadow` , good if you can give us a live demo to let test it.

Comment: I tried it with hex color and also adding live link

Comment: Can check live link at http://csstest.coolpage.biz/